# Rails4 devise paperclip: image not saved in database

Tags: devise, paperclip

Using Rails4 with devise and paperclip my image is not saved in my database.  I'm getting

> Unpermitted parameters: avatar

I added `attr_accessible :avatar` in my `admin/users_controller.rb`

Comment: You may want to include more of the code from `users_controller.rb` for better assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the permitted params:

```
# adjust the fields you need: :avatar, :first_name, :last_name,...
User.create(params.permit(:avatar))
```

See https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters